# ERROR: 42601: Syntax error at or near "'userLogin'"

Tags: c#

I have encountered a problem while executing the following command.

```
 NpgsqlCommand cmd = new NpgsqlCommand("select * from userLogin where userName = :pram0  AND passWord = :pram1", npgsqlConnection);
```

I am trying to retrieve an information in the `userLogin` table and after the `cmd.Prepare()` the error exist.

```
public UserLoginModel GetUserLoginInformation(NpgsqlConnection npgsqlConnection, UserLoginModel loginModel) {
            UserLoginModel userLogin = null;
            try {
                NpgsqlCommand cmd = new NpgsqlCommand("select * from userLogin where userName = :pram0  AND passWord = :pram1", npgsqlConnection);
                cmd.Parameters.Add(new NpgsqlParameter("pram0", DbType.String));
                cmd.Parameters.Add(new NpgsqlParameter("pram1", DbType.String));
                cmd.Prepare();
                cmd.Parameters[0].Value = loginModel.Login_ID;
                cmd.Parameters[1].Value = loginModel.Password;
                NpgsqlDataAdapter dataAdapter = new NpgsqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                DataSet dataSet = new DataSet();
                dataAdapter.Fill(dataSet, "loginTable");
                if (dataSet.Tables["loginTable"].Rows.Count > 0) {
                    userLogin.Proyekto4JuanID = dataSet.Tables["loginTable"].Rows[0]["userID"].ToString();
                    userLogin.Login_ID = dataSet.Tables["loginTable"].Rows[0]["userName"].ToString();
                    userLogin.email = dataSet.Tables["loginTable"].Rows[0]["userEmail"].ToString();
                    userLogin.Password = loginModel.Password;
                    userLogin.AccountType = (int)dataSet.Tables["loginTable"].Rows[0]["accountType"];
                    userLogin.AccountStatus = (int)dataSet.Tables["loginTable"].Rows[0]["accountStatus"];
                }
                this.GetUserProfileInformation(npgsqlConnection, ref userLogin);
                return userLogin;
            } catch (Exception ex) { 
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                return null;
            }
        }
```

How to fix this problem? thank you!

Comment: @RetiredNinja, the title of this question is the error

Comment: I never used npgsql , but according to the docs at https://www.npgsql.org/doc/prepare.html parameters in the query are defined with `@pram1`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found out that the error is in the database. postgres doesn't allow a table name with uppercase like the one above mention `userLogin`.

you just need to change the name of the table in the database to `userlogin`. and it will work.

this gives me so much headache.

by the way, thank you guys for helping me.

Answer (score 2):

It seems odd that this error would come from this code (are you sure it does?) because the error says:

```
near "'userlogin'"
```

Note the apostrophes around the table name, like you've tried to do something like:

```
select * from 'userlogin'
```

That tries to select all from a string, not a table. Check your code for places where you might have used the string `'userlogin'` where the identifier `userlogin` was expected

Comment: I did not use `'userLogin'`. As you can see, The select statement above is `userLogin`.

Comment: I know, but I'm saying it's odd because I can make your exact error message appear with a faulty sql: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=51371ccdaeafb81197d7110b921ecee3 - there doesn't appear to be any fault with the posted code, so I'm saying to double check it's not coming from somewhere else in your code/wanted to point out the extra apostrophes as a clue - they would be easy to miss. A dataadapter wouldn't modify your sql to add apostrophes around a table name, so it's a bit of a puzzle. Have your Ctrl F'd your  C# for 'userLogin'?